How to bypass the 500 characters limit on query resultsets on IBM DB2 Warehouse on Cloud?
I'm running an SQL query on IBM DB2 Warehouse on Cloud, but the results return only the first 500 characters of a string that is longer than that.
Is there a way to bypass this limit?
For example, I ran a query that selects TEXT_DESCRIPTION field (varchar (8K) or CLOB) from a table, but the result returns a short sentence with ellipsis ("this is a long text..."); Hovering the results table cell shows a tooltip with the first 500 characters.
I then tried to export the results to a CSV file, but still, it saves only the first 500 characters.

Clearly, this is a limitation of the web UI; you will need to set up a standard Db2 client and run your export using the Db2 CLI.
